# In D7, Where can you go to get a list of Access Arguments to be used with user_access()?

Tags: 7, users

Where can I find a list of Access Arguments to be used with `user_access()` ? I went to the permissions page and I'm not sure what I can copy and paste from there to be used as an argument for `user_access()`. So far I only know two: 'access dashboard' and 'access content'

I want to find out how can we get a list of these arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of arguments for the site by running this in the terminal:

```
drush sqlq "select distinct(permission) from role_permission \G"
```

[image]

Make sure you clear cache after making permission adjustments. As my changes weren't showing.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, isn't the question what is the machine name for all possible permissions? Wouldn't this be better `drush sqlq "select distinct(permission) from role_permission \G"`

Comment: That's right. I'm not sure how to use distinct. That just shows all the UNIQUE results without duplicates right?

Comment: yes. Another way to write it would be `select distinct permission from role_permission`. In mysql `distinct()` returns all unique rows found in the resultset. it's a nice way to kill your performance. :D but here it's a great solution.